# Upload compiled smart contract got 'f.rpc.contracts.instantiate is not a function'

Tags: pallet-contracts

I implemented contract-pallet in runtime:

```
use pallet_contracts::migration;

pub struct Migrations;
impl OnRuntimeUpgrade for Migrations {
fn on_runtime_upgrade() -> Weight {
 migration::migrate::<Runtime>()
}
}

parameter_types! {
    pub const DepositPerItem: Balance = deposit(1, 0);
    pub const DepositPerByte: Balance = deposit(0, 1);
    pub const MaxValueSize: u32 = 16 * 1024;
    pub const DeletionQueueDepth: u32 = 128;
    pub DeletionWeightLimit: Weight = AVERAGE_ON_INITIALIZE_RATIO * BlockWeights::get().max_block;
    pub Schedule: pallet_contracts::Schedule<Runtime> = Default::default();
}

impl pallet_contracts::Config for Runtime {
    type Time = Timestamp;
    type Randomness = RandomnessCollectiveFlip;
    type Currency = Balances;
    type Event = Event;
    type Call = Call;
    type CallFilter = Nothing;
    type DepositPerItem = DepositPerItem;
    type DepositPerByte = DepositPerByte;
    type CallStack = [pallet_contracts::Frame<Self>; 31];
    type WeightPrice = pallet_transaction_payment::Pallet<Self>;
    type WeightInfo = pallet_contracts::weights::SubstrateWeight<Self>;
    type ChainExtension = ();
    type DeletionQueueDepth = DeletionQueueDepth;
    type DeletionWeightLimit = DeletionWeightLimit;
    type Schedule = Schedule;
    type AddressGenerator = pallet_contracts::DefaultAddressGenerator;
    type ContractAccessWeight = pallet_contracts::DefaultContractAccessWeight<BlockWeights>;
    type MaxCodeLen = ConstU32<{ 128 * 1024 }>;
    type RelaxedMaxCodeLen = ConstU32<{ 256 * 1024 }>;
    type MaxStorageKeyLen = ConstU32<128>;
}
```

When I upload .contract file, console log 'f.rpc.contracts.instantiate is not a function' error. Then I click next after filling parameter for constructor, console log 'The runtime does not expose api.tx.contracts.instantiateWithCode with storageDepositLimit' error. I tried polkadotjs and contract-ui but both returned the same result. How can I fix these errors? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what you added to the runtime, there are some other code snippets you need as well. I recommend finding all areas where `pallet_contracts` is used in the [substrate-contracts-node](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node).

In your runtime, inside the `impl_runtime_apis!` you will need to add the following snippet (found [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node/blob/main/runtime/src/lib.rs#L544)):

```
impl pallet_contracts_rpc_runtime_api::ContractsApi<Block, AccountId, Balance, BlockNumber, Hash>
        for Runtime
    {
        fn call(
            origin: AccountId,
            dest: AccountId,
            value: Balance,
            gas_limit: u64,
            storage_deposit_limit: Option<Balance>,
            input_data: Vec<u8>,
        ) -> pallet_contracts_primitives::ContractExecResult<Balance> {
            Contracts::bare_call(origin, dest, value, Weight::from_ref_time(gas_limit), storage_deposit_limit, input_data, CONTRACTS_DEBUG_OUTPUT)
        }

        fn instantiate(
            origin: AccountId,
            value: Balance,
            gas_limit: u64,
            storage_deposit_limit: Option<Balance>,
            code: pallet_contracts_primitives::Code<Hash>,
            data: Vec<u8>,
            salt: Vec<u8>,
        ) -> pallet_contracts_primitives::ContractInstantiateResult<AccountId, Balance>
        {
            Contracts::bare_instantiate(origin, value,  Weight::from_ref_time(gas_limit), storage_deposit_limit, code, data, salt, CONTRACTS_DEBUG_OUTPUT)
        }

        fn upload_code(
            origin: AccountId,
            code: Vec<u8>,
            storage_deposit_limit: Option<Balance>,
        ) -> pallet_contracts_primitives::CodeUploadResult<Hash, Balance>
        {
            Contracts::bare_upload_code(origin, code, storage_deposit_limit)
        }

        fn get_storage(
            address: AccountId,
            key: Vec<u8>,
        ) -> pallet_contracts_primitives::GetStorageResult {
            Contracts::get_storage(address, key)
        }
    }
```

Additionally, you will need to slightly modify the client RPC as well.
Inside of `node/src/rpc.rs` modify `create_full` (found [here](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/main/node/src/rpc.rs#L30)):

```
pub fn create_full<C, P>(
    deps: FullDeps<C, P>,
) -> Result<RpcModule<()>, Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync>>
where
   // ... snip ...

    // **** ADD THIS ****
    C::Api: pallet_contracts_rpc::ContractsRuntimeApi<Block, AccountId,Balance, BlockNumber, Hash>,
{
    // **** ADD THIS ****
    use pallet_contracts_rpc::{Contracts, ContractsApiServer};

    // ... snip ...

    // Contracts RPC API extension
    // **** ADD THIS ****
    module.merge(Contracts::new(client.clone()).into_rpc())?;

   // ... snip ...
}
```

Comment: Yeah I have these codes but it's just the same as tutorial I'm following so I didn't post it. I only modified ContractAccessWeight and DeletionWeightLimit type there because of some compile error. Do you think the error is from these type?

Comment: @marethyu Hmm, okay. You shouldn't need to modify ContractAccessWeight or DeletionWeightLimit from their defaults to get the node to build. Do you have a link to share to the code?

Comment: If you are only wanting to test ink! smart contracts, you can use the preconfigured contracts node: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node. These tutorials walk through how to use it: https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/smart-contracts/

Comment: Use node template tag polkadot-v0.9.28 works just fine